# Registering to get the client id and client secret in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

I am trying to write a program in java to access the SharePoint using SharePoint REST APIs and download the files in a particular folder inside Documents folder. As the first step which is getting the authentication token, I am trying to register the pp using appregnew.aspx form. As I am new in this area, I am not quite sure what would be my App domain and Request uri. Could someone please help me to understand what are these fields for and what value should be filled in these fields?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could know more about registering SharePoint Add-in from here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/register-sharepoint-add-ins